# QuickForm not working because cannot read property "autoform" of "undefined"

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Cannot figure out why my quickForm is not working.

My code:

```
<template name="newTrip">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            {{> quickForm id="insertTripForm" type="insert" collection="Trips" fields="tripName, destinations"}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

In client folder, I also have a `autoform.js` which has the following 2 lines:

```
AutoForm.setDefaultTemplate('materialize');
AutoForm.debug();
```

No server side errors are being thrown, and on the dev console on chrome, I see this:

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'autoform' of undefined
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?b3aa1a45a8c57d1da1124520538d2cb9fa458509:6819:14
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?46eaedbdeb6e71c82af1b16f51c7da4127d6f285:169:29
    at _.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?46eaedbdeb6e71c82af1b16f51c7da4127d6f285:157:22)
    at Function._.map._.collect (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?46eaedbdeb6e71c82af1b16f51c7da4127d6f285:168:5)
    at getFieldsWithNoGroup (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?b3aa1a45a8c57d1da1124520538d2cb9fa458509:6817:18)
    at Object.quickFormContext (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?b3aa1a45a8c57d1da1124520538d2cb9fa458509:6716:27)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:2986:16
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:1650:16
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:3038:66
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:3671:12)
debug.js:41 Exception from Tracker recompute function:
debug.js:41 TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at null.<anonymous> (autoForm.js:73)
    at view.js:199
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:457)
    at view.js:197
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:538)
    at viewAutorun (view.js:196)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js:323)
    at new Tracker.Computation (tracker.js:211)
    at Object.Tracker.autorun (tracker.js:562)
    at Blaze.View.autorun (view.js:209)
```

What am I doing wrong? I have used quickForms before and cannot figure out what I am doing differently now!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found the problem was a improper capital letter in my SimpleSchema definition of "Trips" (I had used "Schemas.trips" instead of "Schemas.Trips". There was no error related to that, just that it was not working. Leaving this comment here so that other people can be warned / learn from my misery.